# Linux Serial Device Server over USB?

Tags: c, linux, serial-port, usb

I have an embedded Linux solution and want to create a command service over serial USB. The idea being that when a computer connects to my embedded via USB, they see a serial device and send serial commands to me through that port and I send responses back.

I need some help in the direction to proceed. Do I need to emulate a serial device so they see me as a COM port? Is there build in Linux solutions to broadcast my details as a serial device? Are there code examples? I can see block devices connect with my embedded solution like a USB storage device. When I plug into another computer, I would like it to see me as a serial COM port.

I just need help in the direction of which path I should go down to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are operating some weird terms. Do you mean you want to automatically load the device driver once the USB is plugged in? Then look for `udev`.

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is the [Linux USB serial gadget](https://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_serial.txt). The Linux USB gadgets framework allows devices to behave as a variety of standard USB devices, including serial devices, Ethernet adapters, and mass storage devices.

Note that USB gadgets will only work on targets with a USB controller that can be set to operate as a USB device. Not all USB controllers and target devices are compatible with this configuration. For instance, most PCs have a host-only USB controller, and the Raspberry Pi Model B is *not* compatible with gadgets because it contains an embedded USB hub upstream of the USB ports. (However, [the Pi Zero is fully compatible with gadgets](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/overview).)

Comment: *"a USB controller that can be set to operate as a USB device"* -- More often you'll find dedicated Host or Device USB controller ports.  BTW if the target board has USB type B connector, then it should have a USB Device controller port.  If the target board has USB type C (aka OTG) connector, then it could have a USB Device controller port.

Comment: @sawdust It depends more on the SoC than the ports. To reuse an example, the Pi Zero has a micro-USB (type B) port for size reasons, but acts as a host by default.

Comment: Much helpful info here...I will investigate some of the details and return to your advice.

Comment: *"Pi Zero has a micro-USB (type B) port"* -- I've seen it described as an OTG port, which should mean that's a type C, not B.

Comment: @sawdust USB OTG has existed for much longer (15 years) than the type C connector (under 2 years).

Comment: Okay thanks for explaining that.  So the OTG port could have a type AB or C connector, because using a type B for a Host connection seems contrary to USB convention.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than that. Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go for details, but in short, USB OTG is always on a USB type B mini or micro connector. USB C replaces the On-The-Go specification, so it's technically something else.